# Show that a function is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show that $\cos(x^2)$ is not a uniformly continuous function?

I try to choose some value of $x=\sqrt{n\pi}$ and $y=\sqrt{n\pi/2}$ so that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)>\epsilon$, but I got stuck when trying to state the relationship of x and y I picked and $\delta$ in order to make sure that it works for all $\delta$

Comment: As a first step, I highly recommend writing down the definition of uniformly continuous and taking its formal negation to discover what you need to show.

Comment: You'd be better off with $y=\sqrt{n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$, and you could use (because $0<x<y$): $|x-y|=y-x=\frac{y^2-x^2}{x+y}<\frac{y^2-x^2}{2x}$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: What's the domain?  Continuous functions with compact domains are uniformly continuous, always.